# why update is occurred when i want to create a user with an existing mail (am using model validation validates :email, uniqueness: true)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
def create
    user = User.create(user_params)
    if user.save
      flash[:notice] = '#{params[:user][:role]} created successfully'
      redirect_to users_path(role: params[:role])
    else
      flash[:errors] = "#{user.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}"
      redirect_to new_user_path
    end
end
```

This is my `create` method in user controller and am using `invitation gem` file to send invitation.if I use same mail id to create another user then every data to existing user is updated. How can i prevent this from updating user.

Comment: can you please add your model code and error to the OP?

Answer (score 1):

You should add unique email `validation` in your `user` model.

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true
```

Also, refactor your code like this:

```
def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      flash[:notice] = '#{params[:user][:role]} created successfully'
      redirect_to users_path(role: params[:role])
    else
      flash[:errors] = "#{user.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}"
      redirect_to new_user_path
    end
end
```